# Сокращение функции random

Tags: javascript, jquery, оптимизация

Написал функцию рандома для чисел и массивов с исключением. Всё работает, но проблема в том, что код вышел уж слишком большим для такой функции. Как можно оптимизировать (уменьшить) данную функцию?

```js
(function() {
  $.random = function(int__min, int__max, exceptions, tof__integer) {
    if (int__min instanceof Array) {
      var int__min_length = int__min.length - 1,
        arr_exceptions = null;

      if (int__max instanceof Array) {
        arr_exceptions = [];

        $.each(int__max, function(idx, el) {
          arr_exceptions[arr_exceptions.length] = int__min.indexOf(el);
        });
      } else {
        arr_exceptions = int__min.indexOf(int__max);
      };

      return int__min[$.random(0, int__min_length, arr_exceptions, true)];
    } else if (typeof int__min === 'number' && typeof int__max === 'number') {
      if (!int__min) int__min = 0;
      if (!int__max) int__max = 10;
      if (int__min > int__max) {
        var int__min_val = int__min,
          int__max_val = int__max;

        int__min = int__max_val;
        int__max = int__min_val;
      };

      var int__random = null;
      if (tof__integer === undefined || tof__integer === true) {
        int__random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (int__max + 1 - int__min) + int__min);
      } else {
        int__random = Math.random() * (int__max + 0.1 - int__min) + int__min;
      };

      if (typeof exceptions === 'number' || typeof exceptions === 'string') {
        if (exceptions !== int__random) {
          return int__random;
        } else {
          return $.random(int__min, int__max, exceptions, tof__integer);
        };
      } else if (exceptions instanceof Array) {
        var tof__resolution = true;

        $.each(exceptions, function(idx, el) {
          if (int__random === el) tof__resolution = false;
        });

        if (tof__resolution) {
          return int__random;
        } else {
          return $.random(int__min, int__max, exceptions, tof__integer);
        };
      } else {
        return int__random;
      };
    } else {
      console.error('UARR.RANDOM: Invalid values!');
    };
  };
})();

(function() {
  console.log( $.random( 0, 10, null, false ) );
  console.log( $.random( 0, 10, null, true ) );
  console.log( $.random( 0, 10, [5, 6, 7, 8] ) );
  
  console.log( $.random( ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a' ) );
  console.log( $.random( ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'] ) );
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Для чисел:

```
$.random( a, b, c, d );

a - Минимальное число
b - Максимальное число
c - Исключения (число, которое не нужно показывать. Можно указывать массивом)
d - Целые числа или нет (true/false)
```

Для массивов:

```
$.random( a, b );

a - Массив данных
b - Исключения (значения, которые не нужно показывать. Можно указывать массивом)
```

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте избавиться от jquery в зависимостях.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, к сожалению, с JQuery код на оборот меньше чем без него :)

Comment: @Yuri А если саму jQuery посчитать?

Comment: @Yuri Вы в символах считаете или как? Смысл не в том, чтобы сделать код меньше, с этим справится минификатор. Смысл в том, чтобы сделать его проще.

Comment: @Darth, у меня в общем подключен JQuery... так что сделал с его функционалом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не все кейсы понятны (например вот это немного порвало мне мозг -

`console.log( $.random( 0, 10, [5, 6, 7, 8] ) );`

какой тут смысл в exceptions?

Но вот я сделял, в два раза короче и без жуквери:

```js
$ = {};
$.random = function(from, ...args) {
    let results = [];
    let exceptions;
    switch(true){
        case (from instanceof Array):
            exceptions = (args[0] && !(args[0] instanceof Array)) ? [args[0]] : (args[0] || []);
            results = from;
            break;
        case args[2]:
            exceptions = args[1] || [];
            for(let i = from; i<=args[0]; i++) results.push(i);
            break;
        default:
            exceptions = args[1] || [];
            do results = from + (args[0]-from)*Math.random();
            while(exceptions.includes(results));
            return results;
    }
    results = results.filter(el => !exceptions.includes(el));
    return results[Math.floor(Math.random()*results.length)];
};

console.log( $.random( 0, 10, null, false ) );
console.log( $.random( 0, 10, null, true ) );
console.log( $.random( 0, 10, [5, 6, 7, 8], true ) );
console.log( $.random( ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a' ) );
console.log( $.random( ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'] ) );
```

Comment: Вообще подобная функция не должна существовать, потому что по хорошему одна функция должна делать одну вещь.

Comment: На счёт того console.log: то я просто показывал, что исключения массивом можно задавать :) А так, благодарю

Comment: @Yuri Хмм да, я понял.. exceptions для float варианта я таки забыл) Обновил ответ

Comment: @Yuri Вот почитайте, [почему такие функции не стоит делать](https://github.com/maksugr/clean-code-javascript#%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Хмм... а Вы не могли бы показать пример, как эти функции выглядят раздельно? Если не сложно

Comment: Ну, для массивов я бы обошелся такой штукой -  `Array.prototype.random = function(){ return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];};`. для того чтоб отфильровать исключения есть метод filter.